# Get-PnPListItem get item to use it in a condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have a list in a website were I want to get it's isolated result, the title which has a website link, and put it into the variable $item, so I can use it in an If Else condition.
If the website already exists in that list, it will only be updated, if dont, it will create a new one.
My code is working but the getpnplistitem is not isolating the result and sending it to the variable, what can I do next?

```
function Logs{
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Insert template version")]
        [string]
        $TemplateVersion
        )

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url "website.sharepoint.com"

    $date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" 

    Add-PnPListItem -List "Execution Logs" -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"Timestamp" =$date;"TemplateVersion" =$TemplateVersion}

    $Url = "https://website.sharepoint.com"

    $item = Get-PnPListItem -List "Deployment Status" -Query "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>$Url</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

    if($Url -eq $item){

        Set-PnPListItem -List "Deployment Status" -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"CurrentTemplate" =$TemplateVersion}                

        }

    else{

        Add-PnPListItem -List "Deployment Status" -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"CurrentTemplate" =$TemplateVersion}

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate the below in your function. It check the count of items and then if exist update the list items and adds if it doesn't exists.

Note: Update the list and column names before using it.

```
$url="www.google1.com"
$templateVersion="Template TEST Three"

$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "Contact" -Query "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>$Url</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

$items.Count

if($items.Count -gt 0) # one or more items exist
{
  foreach($item in $items) #update each item that already exists
  {
    Set-PnPListItem -List "Contact" -Identity $item.Id  -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"TemplateVersion" =$TemplateVersion}   
  }

}
else #add an item if not already exists
{
  Add-PnPListItem -List "Contact" -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"TemplateVersion" =$TemplateVersion}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the condition `if($Url -eq $item)`, you could use `if($item -eq $null)` instead.

```
if($item -eq $null){
 Add-PnPListItem -List "Deployment Status" -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"CurrentTemplate" =$TemplateVersion}
}
else{
Set-PnPListItem -List "Contact" -Identity $item.Id  -Values @{"Title" = $Url;"TemplateVersion" =$TemplateVersion}   
    }
```